# Update an other field when a count is on a certain value

Tags: vue.js, symfony, graphql, apollo

Hi i'm actually working on a report system for my social network, i want to achieve something like : if a user is reported 5 times it will update a field on the user table to deactivate the user.

So if 5 row of reports is created i want to update the "activated" field

The thing is i'm working with GraphQL and Vue for the first time, my backend is in Symfony with ApiPlatform.

Should i try to query all the reports with the userId who is reported to count if there is 5 row when a user is reported and then mutate the user object to deactivate it or can i achieve this more easily on the backend side ?

Answer (score 0):

So anything of importance should be done on the backend. The frontend is easily hacked and while it's good to stop normal (good) users from seeing something they're not supposed to, it's not a blocker to anyone who has even rudimentary web coding ability.

Seeing as you're talking about someone being reported, I'd recommend doing it on the backend and then make sure the frontend reflects that gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the thing is i do not know how i can achieve this with symfony, it's the first time i'm using graphql and api, it's like i have 0 control of what's happening behind the scenes and i do not know where to modify/edit to do this..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know symfony. Sounds like a multi-step and multi-tech issue which is hard to get answers for (especially here). Maybe ask another question specifically targeting what you're stuck on (symfony only). And you have much better chance of an answer if you show you have something - so maybe YouTube a course and see if you can learn enough to get something to support your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hum it seems that the answer is that i need a reportListener and i need to listen the postPersist event, then inside this function i can check how many report there is for a user using the ReportRepository->findBy function, then i can count the row of the array return by the function and if the count is > 5 then i edit my user, persist and flush.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).